# How to save array item clicked on to sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a listview with an array in it. I am trying to save the item when it is clicked to my database so that I can recall which items have been checked on startup.

```
          if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES (item.toString)");

                if (score < 1119) {
                    score++;

                } else {
                    score++;
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            levelFinishedConstraint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }, 1000);
                }
            } else {

                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM list WHERE found = item.toString");
                score = score - 1;


            }
```

As it stands the app is crashing when I click a list item.

```
 Process: com.example.woodlandwanderer, PID: 14080
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: item.toString (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES (item.toString)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1752)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1682)
        at com.example.woodlandwanderer.levelOneActivity$2.onItemClick(levelOneActivity.java:121)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: You edited your question and posted a totally different question, so all the answers you already received are now invalidated. This is not how it works. Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 0):

> `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: item.toString (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES (item.toString)`

That error is due to the item.toString not being enclosed in single quotation marks. That could be fixed by using :-

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES ('item.toString')");
```

**BUT** do you really want to insert a row where the found column has the value "item.toString". I very much doubt it and you may very well end up with numerous rows all with the same probably useless value.

What you appear to want is :-

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES (?)", new String[]{item.toString});
```

Then the value that would be inserted would be whatever the **item**'s **toString** method returns. That is the **?** is replaced by the items in the Array (the first ? replaced by the first element of the array, the 2nd ? by the 2nd element and so on). In replacing the ? the correct enclosures are also used.

An alternative but not recommend way would be to use :-

*`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES ('" + item.toString + "')");`*

- This is not recommended as it's open to the potential for SQL Injection.

**Likewise**,

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM list WHERE found = item.toString");
```

Will have the same issues, that should be :-

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM list WHERE found = ?",new String[]{item.toString});
```

Comment: the toString part is bringing up error; cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @greenpony Then item is not an object and there is insufficient code to determine what the exact issue is with item. It didn't complain before because item.toString was used a value. *If you used `db.execSQL("INSERT INTO list(found) VALUES (?)", new String[]{"Fred"});` then the value **Fred** would be stored in the found column of the list table (assuming that the tables exists and there are no other reasons for the insert to fail)*.

Answer (score 0):

Since item is some object I guess and you want it's StringResult, try

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM list WHERE found = '" + item.toString + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)

> public void execSQL(String sql) 
>  Execute a single SQL statement
>   that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

So you could use this overload of `execSQL()` to insert or delete data but you would also have to concatenate the parameter that you want to pass with single quotes and this is not safe as it leaves your app wide open to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
Also from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)

> public void execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs) 
>   Execute a single
>   SQL statement that is **NOT** a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

So [`execSQL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) is **not** the recommended way to insert or delete rows.
Instead use the method [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) by supplying the column values in a `ContentValues` object and the method [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("found", item.toString);
boolean inserted = db.insert("list", null, cv) > 0;
```

You can check the `boolean` variable `inserted` after this code to get if the insertion was successful.
And to delete the row:

```
boolean deleted = db.delete("list", "found = ?", new String[] {item.toString}) > 0;
```

You can check the `boolean` variable `deleted` after this code to get if the deletion was successful.
For this code to work you must have initialized the variable `db` properly and the name of the table must be `"list"` and the column's name `"found"`.
Also make sure that `item.toString()` returns the value that you want to search for.